# Is this a control? (C# Winforms)

Tags: c#, winforms

Is there a `<hr></hr>` like in winforms? I just saw this line in a property window of an icon, is it a control or what? How can I add it into my form? Please see image:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In C#, you can use the LineShape via Visual Basic PowerPacks.

Comment: What comes next after installing?

Comment: The PowerPacks came preinstalled in VS 2008 +, but I'm not sure about earlier versions. Once you've installed it, the LineShape should be available in the control toolbox in the Winforms designer.

Answer (score 2):

This is not a standard windows controls. This is simply a panel of height 1 and dark background.

Answer (score 1):

No, no, it's just label or panel control with gray background and height=1.
If you need to have 3D line, use apropriate border style and height=2.